# pgfplots - insufficient precision

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, gnuplot

I am having the following problem: Using pgfplots to plot some convergence graphs, I have to load a text file and do some computations. Most of the time everythings works just fine. But in some situations, the 4-6 significant digits for pgfplots are insufficient.

How can I modify the following code to get my desired graphs?
I have read about using gnuplot, but I could not find a similar example for my particular usecase. And the pgfplots manual does say anything about loading a table and doing computaions in gnuplot ot the shell in Sections 4.2.6 or 4.2.7. Is there another way to achieve this? I do have a lot of graphs to generate, so a semi-automatic solution as with the pgfplots code below would be preferable.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{semilogyaxis}
        \addplot table[x expr={\thisrowno{0}^0.2}, y expr={sqrt(abs(0.80336293803-\thisrowno{}))}] {data/convRates.txt};
    \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

convRates.txt

```
1       0.6123724356960
155     0.8002396840450
1115        0.8032455664310
4519        0.8033592830220
13391       0.8033626913420
32579       0.8033629179460
69187       0.8033629362110
133007      0.8033629378560
236951      0.8033629380130
397483      0.8033629380290
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you tried using the floating point library?

Comment: Hallo, reading the manual, I thought `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}`was activated by default using the `\addplot table`command. However, setting this explicitely in the preamble I know get a lot of errors: “[...] floating point unit got an ill-formed floating point number near [...]” So I guess that fpu was not set to true ...

Comment: @erniepb These errors are due to the fact that you try to use comma as decimal separator which is not really supported.  Please always use the period instead!

Comment: @Henri Menke: In fact I am using the dot for the decimal separator, but copied the selected columns from libreoffice with a comma. Fixed this in the question.

Comment: @Henri Menke: Despite your (very nice) answer. Wha could be the reason for the many errors when I set `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}`. It is definitely not the comma-separator as I am actually using the period-separator.

Comment: @erniepb This is due to the way floating point numbers are represented by PGF.  For example `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}\pgfmathparse{1.0}` will leave `\pgfmathresult=macro:->1Y1.0e0]` which is the internal representation of floating point numbers.  Unfortunately, `pgfplots` assumes that `\pgfmathparse{1.0}` is going to result in `\pgfmathresult=macro:->1.0`.  The parser cannot convert things like `1Y1.0e0` properly and bombards you with errors.

Comment: @Henri Menke: Ahhh, again thank you very much for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `pgfplots` to evaluate the expression you could use `l3fp` which guarantees full 16-digit floating point precision.

Also, always use period as the decimal separator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand \eval { m } { \fp_eval:n { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{semilogyaxis}
    \addplot table [
    x expr={\eval{(\thisrowno{0})^0.2}},
    y expr={\eval{sqrt(abs(0.80336293803-\thisrowno{1}))}}
    ] {
      1      0.6123724356960
      155    0.8002396840450
      1115   0.8032455664310
      4519   0.8033592830220
      13391  0.8033626913420
      32579  0.8033629179460
      69187  0.8033629362110
      133007 0.8033629378560
      236951 0.8033629380130
      397483 0.8033629380290
    };
  \end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: @erniepb So sorry, see updated answer.